# TypeScript, const/enums type

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have the following const/enum:

```
export const LENGTH_LIMIT = {
  MAX_INPUT_CUSTOMER_FORM: '500',
  MAX_INPUT_EMPLOYEE_FORM: '500'
};
```

I would like to give it a type. But can i give `LENGTH_LIMIT` a type besides `any`? Or is `any` the only thing which would work here?

Comment: This isn't an enum, it's an object. Enums are declared with the keyword `enum`. The difference is that enums won't generate any javascript code to represent the object, but it will replace all its usages (for example `LENGTH_LIMIT.MAX_INPUT_CUSTOMER_FORM`) with its value ('500')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) That's an object, not an enum

2) Why do you want to give constants a type? Typescript already infers them for you. It infers this:

```
interface LenghtLimit {
    MAX_INPUT_CUSTOMER_FORM: string,
    MAX_INPUT_EMPLOYEE_FORM: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TypeScript enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) for this. Then, the type would be the enum itself:

```js
export enum LENGTH_LIMIT {
  MAX_INPUT_CUSTOMER_FORM = '500',
  MAX_INPUT_EMPLOYEE_FORM = '500',
}
```

And to use it:

```js
interface CustomerForm {
    InputLimit: LENGTH_LIMIT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an interface for example:

```
interface LengthLimit {
    [name: string || any]: string
}
```

then:

```
export const LENGTH_LIMIT : LengthLimit = {
  MAX_INPUT_CUSTOMER_FORM: '500',
  MAX_INPUT_EMPLOYEE_FORM: '500'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want declare as enum:

```
export enum LENGTH_LIMIT {
  MAX_INPUT_CUSTOMER_FORM = '500',
  MAX_INPUT_EMPLOYEE_FORM = '500',
}
```

If you want to use a variable of type LENGTH_LIMIT in HTML template you must assign it:

```
LengthLimitOptions: any = LENGTH_LIMIT;
```

And in HTML use as:

```
<span>{{LengthLimitOptions.MAX_INPUT_EMPLOYEE_FORM}}</span>
```